# Error: replacement has 1810947 rows and data has 1810956 (same each time) for pupil data

Tags: r, interpolation, eye-tracking, na.approx

I have a large dataframe in R (data) made up of 23 .gazedata files (one for each subject):

```
filenames <- list.files("~/Desktop/DUT Analyses 2019", pattern = "*.gazedata", full.names = TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read_tsv)
data <- do.call("rbind", ldf)
```

After creating factors and timing variables, I create the pupil variable, based on default validity parameters collected by the eye-tracker:

```
data$DiameterPupilLeftEye[data$ValidityLeftEye != 0] <- NA
data$DiameterPupilRightEye[data$ValidityRightEye != 0] <- NA
data$pupil = rowMeans(select(data, DiameterPupilLeftEye, DiameterPupilRightEye), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now, I need to create an interpolated pupil variable (pupil_inter) to interpolate values to a maximum gap of 4:

```
data$pupil_inter<- na.approx(data$pupil, rule = 2, maxgap = 4)
```

However, the following error occurs:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, pupil_inter, value = c(4.2120165, 4.20966425,  : 


replacement has 1810947 rows, data has 1810956
```

These row amounts are exactly the same every time.

***Crucially, if I exclude subjects 22 & 23 .gazedata files from the pre-processing, the latter code works and there is no error***

I have tried identifying an existing "replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]" problem to help with my specific issue, but can't find a relevant solution. All .gazedata files were collected using the same hardware and software.

The error persists, even when successfully creating a null pupil_inter variable first, using the following code:

```
data$pupil_inter <- NA
```

Thanks in advance for any advice offered.

Comment: Just a guess, as I don't have access to your data... Does `data$pupil_inter<- na.approx(data$pupil, rule = 2, maxgap = 4, na.rm = FALSE)` work?

Comment: That worked, thank you. Apologies it was so simple. I shall close the question, thanks again!

Comment: I'll add it as a proper answer with an explanation so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because the `na.approx()` function is returning fewer rows than you're passing in, so you're trying to append a column that has 1,810,947 rows to a dataframe that has 1,810,956 rows. Having a look at the documentation for `na.approx()`, I see that there's an `na.rm` parameter. When that is true (which it is by default), it will remove `NAs` from the returned value and you will have fewer rows than you started with. If you set it to false, the `NAs` will be returned and you should have the same number of rows. Try this:

```
data$pupil_inter<- na.approx(data$pupil, rule = 2, maxgap = 4, na.rm = FALSE)
```